# How to hide the bubble when placing the cursor on option-label?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, swatches

I wish to hide this information, because it is useless :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just hide using CSS.

Put this code you css file

```
.swatch-attribute-label { z-index: 99999;}
.swatch-option-tooltip {    max-width: 0px !important;    max-height: 0px !important;    overflow:hidden;    min-height: 0px !important;    min-width: 0px !important; border:none !important;    background:transparent !important; 
}
```

**OutPut:-**

[image]

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Thank you, the code worked !